# How do I pretty-print a Rust HashMap in GDB?

Tags: hashmap, rust, gdb

Here is a simple Rust example with a `Vec` and `HashMap` that I am running in GDB:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let v = vec!["Mon", "Tue", "Wed"];
    println!("{:?}", v);

    let mut h = HashMap::new();
    h.insert(1,"Jan");
    h.insert(2,"Feb");
    h.insert(3,"Mar");
    h.insert(4,"Apr");
    println!("{:?}", h);
}
```

When I view the `Vec` it is pretty-printed, while the `HashMap` isn't:

```
bash$ rust-gdb target/debug/test_hashmap
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.1
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from target/debug/test_hashmap...done.
(gdb) b 12
Breakpoint 1 at 0xa056: file src/main.rs, line 12.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/john/proj/test_hashmap/target/debug/test_hashmap 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1".
["Mon", "Tue", "Wed"]

Breakpoint 1, test_hashmap::main () at src/main.rs:12
12          println!("{:?}", h);
(gdb) p v
$1 = Vec<&str>(len: 3, cap: 3) = {"Mon", "Tue", "Wed"}
(gdb) p h
$2 = HashMap<i32, &str, std::collections::hash::map::RandomState> = {hash_builder = RandomState = {k0 = 12919411587537124140, 
    k1 = 836420561220520453}, table = RawTable<i32, &str> = {capacity_mask = 31, size = 4, hashes = TaggedHashUintPtr = {
      Unique<usize> = {pointer = NonZero<*const usize> = {0x7ffff6c1c400}, _marker = PhantomData<usize>}}, 
    marker = PhantomData<(i32, &str)>}, resize_policy = DefaultResizePolicy}
(gdb) info pretty-printer
global pretty-printers:
  builtin
    mpx_bound128
  objfile /home/john/proj/test_hashmap/target/debug/test_hashmap pretty-printers:
  rust_pretty_printer_lookup_function
(gdb) n
{1: "Jan", 4: "Apr", 3: "Mar", 2: "Feb"}
13      }
(gdb)
```

The program sees the `HashMap` (and prints its values ok), but I can't see those inside GDB. The Rust pretty printer seems to be enabled because `Vec` is printed out just fine.

How can I get the `HashMap` keys and values in regular GDB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment it is not possible to pretty-print key-values items for an `HashMap`.

There is [an open issue requesting this feature](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/41082).

Comment: Is there any way to see the values at all? That issue thread mentions you can print the memory after PhantomData marker... My gdb-guy is a bit rusty. :-) Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Pretty printing a `BTreeMap` will be enabled if [this PR is merged](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/53357).

Both BTreeMap and HashMap APIs are similar. So, you may be able to replace `HashMap` and `BTreeMap` for debugging.

Comment: @fukatani: First of all, thank you for contributing the pretty printers. Regarding asking to remove a downvote, it's certainly possible, however it's unlikely to succeed unless you can convince the downvoter that you are right OR fix whatever flaw of the answer they perceived to be worth a downvote. I would note that beyond the offending comment here; there's the issue that the OP is asking about `HashMap` and you are replying for `BTreeMap`; so while it's useful information, it seems only marginally related to the issue at hand.

Comment: @fukatani - thank you, this is good news. Looks like it is merged already. May be this will help me to figure out the one for HashMap!

Comment: @Shepmaster I tried, but `HashMap` is difficult for me. I think that one of the reasonable methods at the current version is to use BTreeMap only for debugging. Forgive me.

Comment: @MatthieuM. So should I remove my answer?

Comment: @fukatani: I am afraid it would be for the best. What you could do, if you wish, is create another question named "How to pretty-print a BTreeMap in gdb?" which shows the current situation, then self-answer it with a link to your patch and a demonstration of the output after the patch. (When asking, there's a box to tick to so you can post both question and answer in one go). This way, people looking to print their BTreeMap would be aware they can upgrade to get it.

Comment: @fukatani -- if you end up posting this in a separate answer -- leave a link to this one. I am sure that people who are searching for this will be interested in both `BTreeMap` and `HashMap`. I know I am -- and i found your answer very useful. @Shepmaster -- for `HashMap` I couldn't figure out to how even see the values "by hand", let alone pretty print them. `marker = PhantomData<(i32, &str)>` is probably the key to this, but for the life of me I can't locate where the pointers for keys and values are...

Comment: I already removed performance description and showed my answer is strongly related to question. But unfortunately, downvote continues.

I do not have the energy to separate question. I'm tired of the stackoverflow and rust community so I'm leaving. It does not seem to be suitable for me.
Discussion is continuing, so I'll leave this answer as it is. Thanks!

Comment: @fukatani Please don't let us pedantic people here on Stack Overflow detract from the greater Rust community. Stack Overflow has specific standards that we seek to uphold to make the Q&A as useful as possible, and these guidelines do not fit everyone's personality. However, Rust is bigger than just Stack Overflow and has many other avenues like the user's forum, IRC, Discord, etc. You may find one or more of these more suitable to your own specific style. FWIW, I also thank you for adding that support, even though I use LLDB instead of GDB ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can use rust-gdb/rust-lldb, it can pretty-print key-values items for an HashMap.